# Are there any automation test example source code using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, testing, automation

Are there any source code example of software automation testing with **System.Windows.Automation**?

because i'm realy having problems with this...

Answer (score 2):

These links should give you a start:

[System.Windows.Automation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hilliao/archive/2008/08/20/system-windows-automation.aspx)

[The Microsoft UI Automation Library (MSDN article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx)

Comment: The second link is dead. Look in the February 2008 issue

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [White](http://white.codeplex.com/). It uses the System.Windows.Automation heavily and includes a lot of samples and tests.