# Click on 'OK' button of message box using WinAPI in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, messagebox

I am trying to click on 'OK' button on a message box of C# Windows Forms using WinAPI . Below is the code that I am working on.

```
private const int WM_CLOSE = 16;
private const int BN_CLICKED = 245;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string  windowTitle);

// this works
hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Message");
if(hwnd!=0)
      SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

// this doesn't work.
hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "ok");
SendMessage((int)hwndChild, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Though I get a value in `hwndChild`, it is not recognising `BN_CLICKED`.
I am not sure what am I missing. any help?

I am trying to close the message box button of another application and this is what I am doing. But, I m still missing something.

```
IntPtr hwndChild = IntPtr.Zero;
hwndChild = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwnd, IntPtr.Zero,' '"Button", "OK");
SendMessage((int)hwndChild, WM_COMMAND, (BN_CLICKED '<<16) | IDOK, hwndChild);
```

Comment: Since you're using C#, you may as well use the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace. Here's an example that [pushes the "7" button in Calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108742/manipulating-the-simple-windows-calculator-using-win32-api-in-c/14111246#14111246). Just change "Calculator" to "Message" and "7" to "OK".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finallu, this works for me. 
First click probably activates the window and second click clicks the button.

```
SendMessage(btnHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
SendMessage(btnHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
SendMessage(btnHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
SendMessage(btnHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks i had problem to click on button inside dialog. Your sollution to click twice helped me. As you said 1st click activate window and second send message to click.

Answer (score 14):

BN_CLICKED is not a message. You need to send a WM_COMMAND message containing the [BN_CLICKED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notification and the button ID in the `wParam` and the button handle in `lParam`.

> The parent window of the button receives this notification code
> through the WM_COMMAND message.

```
private const uint WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
private const int BN_CLICKED = 245;
private const int IDOK = 1;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string  windowTitle);

SendMessage(hwndChild, WM_COMMAND, (BN_CLICKED << 16) | IDOK, hwndChild);
```