# Automatically press a button or accept a dialog in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click

Is there a way to automatically click on "OK" button of `MessageBox.Show("my message");`?
I don't want to remove the `MessageBox`, because it lets me capture a screenshot ([More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498762/more-time-between-each-screenshot-partially-resolved))

**OR**

Is there a way to hold the `Enter` key pressed for `X` seconds? (Very dirty approach, but it could work).

Edit: I've found this code for `WPF`, though I don't know how I could implement it for my `MessageBox`:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer =  new ButtonAutomationPeer( someButton );

IInvokeProvider invokeProv =  peer.GetPattern( PatternInterface.Invoke )
  as IInvokeProvider;

invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Edit2: If only I could *call* the button of the message box I could use the code written above for having the task done. Does anyone know how to call that button?

I've tried this but with no succes:

```
var mensaje = MessageBox.Show("Hello Stack Overflow!", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
```

Comment: If message box is always on top you can try by sending "Enter" key http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm working under WPF and as far as I know there is no such method there. =(

Comment: Use [popupkiller](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2772/C-Popup-Killer)

Comment: Are you using the Winforms or Wpf MessageBox

Comment: This requires the Windows API, but looks like it works.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962081/click-on-ok-button-of-message-box-using-winapi-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed this with user32.dll

Answer (score 0):

The code will "stop" when you say `MessageBox.Show`. So if you need some times to auto-answer a DialogBox then create a Custom MessageBox. It is very easy to create one and also you can arrange it;s behavior as you want every time.