# Creating a program that monitors dialogues in Windows then clicks on OK automatically

Tags: windows, monitoring, desktop

I'm looking to create a program for Windows that monitors on the desktop if there are any dialogues popping up.

If it does, it should click on OK automatically. How do I create such a program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962081/click-on-ok-button-of-message-box-using-winapi-in-c-sharp

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.