# automationElement.RootElement.FindFirst always returns null

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I have a requirement that may need to use something like UI Automation so i'm trying to learn the basics but I'm not having much luck.

I found this line of code in a couple of examples from different articles:

```
var calcWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator"));
```

but whenever I run this line, calcWindow is null. I've noticed that it will be set to a value when I run 2 instances of the calculator.

The same problem applies to RootElement.FindAll where it returns null when a single instance of the calculator runs but when I run 2 instances, it will return a value and its .Count() property is set to 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I probably should have included the articles I was looking at:

- [manipulating the simple windows Calculator using win32 API in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108742/manipulating-the-simple-windows-calculator-using-win32-api-in-c)
- [Automate your UI using Microsoft Automation Framework](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/141842/automate-your-ui-using-microsoft-automation-framew)

Note that I'm running these tests using .NET 2015 on a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (os build: 17134.112 - version: 1803).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows 10 the calculator is a UWP app so you need to use a different method to find it.

Here is an example of how [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.Core/Application.cs#L250) is getting the new calculator vs the legacy calculator. FlaUI is written on top of both the managed UIAv2 API and the unmanaged UIAv3 COM wrapper.

```
    protected override Application StartApplication()
    {
        if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows10())
        {
            // Use the store application on those systems
            return Application.LaunchStoreApp("Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
        }
        if (OperatingSystem.IsWindowsServer2016())
        {
            // The calc.exe on this system is just a stub which launches win32calc.exe
            return Application.Launch("win32calc.exe");
        }
        return Application.Launch("calc.exe");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Was stuck on other part of project but that's great! Thanks Max.